# How to deploy one application on multiple EC2 instances at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5

I have one rails application and I want to deploy this application on multiple AWS EC2 instances at the same time. Means if I deploy the app on x instance then it would automatically deploy on Y and Z instances. How?

Can anyone explain how to do this? What are the steps I need to follow on AWS?

A detailed explanation or direction towards some resources on the topic will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of potential ways to deploy a Rails app to AWS. One of the more straightforward ways is with Elastic Beanstalk, which you can read more about here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ruby-rails-tutorial.html

Comment: Agreed @hephalump. But can we deploy an app on multiple instances with Elastic Beanstalk at the same time? If yes, then how?

Comment: Yes, just set the minimum number of instances you want in your AutoScaling group in ElasticBeanstalk... ElasticBeanstalk will handle deployment to those instances.